# Can we rename a plugin directory for a already launched plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory

I have launched a plugin long back on WordPress.org and now I want to change the name of the main directory of plugin due to some reason. But I want to retain the old name of the plugin. Is it allowed by Wordpress:

- to change the directory name after release?
- to have directory name different from the main-plugin-file.php & plugin-name?

Will there be any other impact if we do a new release with changed directory name?

Comment: Is the plugin hosted on wordpress.org?

Comment: Yes, the plugin is hosted on wordpress.org. I also edited the question accordingly.

Comment: If you do this the plugin will be deactivated when people update, because active plugins is stored as 'directory-name/file-name.php`, meaning that if that directory changes it won't be in the list of active plugins.